# 2008 Hyundai Santa Fe - the door fob has quit and locks are acting strange!

Tags: hyundai, locks, door, fob, santa-fe

I have a recently purchased 2008 Hyundai Santa Fe with 160,000 miles. I am shipping the car to the Virgin Islands. I walked out yesterday and the fob for the door locks wasn't working. Changed the fob battery, nothing. When you open the door it is like there is a key in the ignition. The same sound but there are no keys in the car. If you lock the driver's door from the inside it will lock the unlock. Same on the passenger door, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!